# How to debug ajax request in IE browser?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

I have tried to update from admin panel using the IE browser via ajax request, the data is also successfully updated in the database but when I again, try to edit, the previous data occurs, but the updated data does not shown in that edited input text.

This issue is only shown in the IE but not in Chrome and Firefox. Is there any solution for this how to view the ajax request in the IE browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `F12` if you are using `IE8` or up or install firebug for `IE`.

```
www.firebugger.com/
```

or

```
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E)
{if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?
Fi+'NS':Fi;Er;Er;Er;(Fe[0]||Fe[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;Er;})
(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite',
'4', 'firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png',
'https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

Just paste that string into the address bar in IE after you've loaded your page.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 if you are using IE8 or up or install firebug for IE.

www.firebugger.com/

or

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite